# method based on variable type

Tags: class, c#-4.0, design-patterns, methods

I just have the following scenario 
i want to return string from method but the method should be based on variable type which is (`Type CType`)

i need to make the render class like this

```
public string render(TextBox ctype){
return "its text box";
}
public string render(DropDown ctype){
return "its drop down";
}
```

you know TextBox is a Type thats why i can declare the Type variable like this

```
var CType = typeof(TextBox)
```

and i need to call the render method like this

```
render(Ctype);
```

so if the Ctype is type of TextBox it should call the render(TextBox ctype)
and so on 
How can i make it ?

Comment: Is it known at compile-time what type is passed to the `render` method, or only at runtime?

Comment: in run time i would call render but i dont know the ctype type @O.R.Mapper

Answer (score 0):

you should use a template function

```
public customRender<T>(T ctype)
{
    if(ctype is TextBox){
        //render textbox
    }
    else if(ctype is DropDown){
        //render dropdown
    }
}
```

hope it will help

Comment: In that case, what good is the generic parameter? Why not just type `ctype` to `Control` and drop the generic parameter?

Comment: the problem is i dont want to use If or switch case

Comment: what do you mean @O.R.Mapper?

Comment: @M.NourBerro: The method suggested in this answer could just as well be declared as, e.g.: `public void customRender(object ctype)`. With the implementation described here, there is no need for the generic parameter `<T>`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper i know but i dont want to use any if or switch

Answer (score 0):

First of all, even if you don't `see` an `if` or a `switch`, there will still be one somewhere hidden inside some functions. Distinguishing types at runtime that are not known at compile-time simply will not be possible without any such kind of branching of the control flow.

You can use one of the collection classes to build a map at runtime that maps [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances to [`Func<T, TResult>` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example, you can use the [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type to create such a map:

```
var rendererFuncs = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>();
```

You could then add some entries to that dictionary like this:

```
rendererFuncs[typeof(TextBox)] = ctype => "its text box";
rendererFuncs[typeof(DropDown)] = ctype => "its drop down";
```

Later on, you can call the appropriate function like this:

```
string renderedValue = rendererFuncs[Ctype.GetType()](Ctype);
```

Or, if you want to be on the safe side (in case there are `Ctype` values that have no appropriate renderer):

```
string renderedValue;
Func<object, string> renderer;
if (rendererFuncs.TryGetValue(Ctype.GetType(), out renderer)) {
    renderedValue = renderer(Ctype);
} else {
    renderedValue = "(no renderer found)";
}
```

Note that this will only work for as long as `Ctype` is of the exact type used as a key in the dictionary; if you want any subtypes to be correctly recognized as well, drop the dictionary and build your own map that traverses the inheritance hierarchy of the type being searched (by using the [`Type.BaseType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: i will test it and tell you the result thanks for your answer :)